# database design and ERD for a fairly complex music-taste-sharing web app

Tags: database-design, erd

I am trying to design a Database for a music-taste-sharing web application.

I pretty much never have to do Db design/architecture and thought I'd get some help from SO users and hopefully my question could become a nice example of "good" Db design practices.

FYI: The ERD was drawn using ***MySQL Workbench*** which is a FREE software.

***These are my requirements and how I represented them in the Db schema***

- user has credentials & an account/profile (email, fName, lName, & so on) - all this is under the `USER_DETAILS` table
- user can have role(s) & & several users can have the same role(s) - hence the *many-to-many* relationship between `USER_DETAILS` & `ROLE` tables
- user can have images - hence the *one-to-many* relationship between `USER_DETAILS` & `USER_IMAGE` tables
- user can have many badges & several users can have the same badge(s) - hence the *many-to-many* relationship between `USER_DETAILS` & `BADGE` tables
- user's track can have many reputation history & a reputation history is only matching one specific user's track - hence the *one-to-many* relationship between `USER_DETAILS_TRACK` & `REPUTATION_HISTORY` tables
- user can have many tracks & several users can have the same track(s) - hence the *many-to-many* relationship between `USER_DETAILS` & `TRACK` tables
- user can have tag(s) per track & several users can have the same tag(s) per track - hence the *many-to-many* relationship between `USER_DETAILS_TRACK` & `TAG_2` tables
- track is represented under has `TRACK` table
- track can have several artists & an artist can be in several tracks - hence the *many-to-many* relationship between `TRACK` & `ARTIST` tables
- track can have several releases & an releases can (& usually) have several tracks - hence the *many-to-many* relationship between `TRACK` & `RELEASE` tables
- release has one release_type & a release_type can be in many releases - hence the *one-to-many* relationship between `RELEASE_TYPE` & `RELEASE` tables (a release type would be an album, an EP, an LP, a single & so on)
- track can have comments - hence the *one-to-many* relationship between `TRACK` & `COMMENT` tables
- track can have several tags & an artist can be in several tracks - hence the *many-to-many* relationship between `TRACK` & `TAG_1` tables

You must have noticed that I have duplicated the TAG table has TAG_1 & TAG_2. Ideally I would only have one but I am afraid that would create a coupling far too strong between `USER_DETAILS_TRACK` & `TRACK` tables as these are already linked with a *many-to-one* relationship.

I plan to keep TAG_1 & TAG_2 synchronized in the middle tier.

[image: INITIAL ERD Diagram for "my fairly complex music-taste-sharing web app"]

---

Latest edit after podiluska's comments

[image: LATEST ERD Diagram for "my fairly complex music-taste-sharing web app"]

1. Am I on the right path regarding my db design?
2. What would you modify/improve?

Thanks a LOT

Comment: If reputation history is linked to user_details and track, why is not linked to user_details_track via user_details_track_id?

Comment: I just updated my question with a schema change after your suggestion. It looks a bit heavy to me, doesn't it? would that work?

Comment: I would link to `user_details_track`, not `user_details` and `track`

Comment: thx. corrected by a one-to-many between `user_details_track` & `reputation_history` since a track can appear several time in the same user's reputation history.

Comment: That'd be 'album', 'EP', 'LP' & so on. The idea is to focus on track themselves so I have decided not to create a table for Release_Type neither for Release_Name but rather put them directly into the Track table directly.

Comment: If you're going to store `release_type` I'd create a table for the lookup values.

Comment: I updated the schema with two more tables: `RELEASE` holding the name and date of the release & `RELEASE_TYPE` holding the type of release ('album', 'EP', 'LP' & so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the adjustments made in the comments, I think it's now more or less there.

You need to either remove Track_ID from Release and replace it with Release_ID in track, or have a TrackRelease table - depending on whether a track can be on more than one release, and vice versa.

Comment: Updated the description and schema: track can have several releases & an releases can (& usually) have several tracks - hence the many-to-many relationship between TRACK & RELEASE tables. Thx again for your help, this looks much better than the initial ERD diagram :)